# Where is the executable after building the file in Visual Studio Community?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, executable

I finished building hello world program in C++ Visual Studio Community. When I search for the executable file (that supposedly creates a .exe file), i am unable to locate. There are no errors and the program runs fine.

What am i missing?

Comment: The Output Window in Visual Studio will show you the name of the file(s) that were built.

Comment: Usually in the x64/Debug or x64/Release directory under the directory where the solution file is. If you're building for 32-bit it's just the Debug or Release directory.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click your project-> properties: Linker->  General-> Output File: Click down arrow, then edit it.

You could check the value of the macro:  `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`

Comment: HI,@J Frey  May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?